# ListView scrolling choppy and slow on Android

Tags: javascript, android, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile, angular-kendo

I am building a Kendo UI Mobile + AngularJS application.
I have a listview with a variable number of results, could be anything between 5 and 500.

The scrolling of the listview on Android is bad. It is choppy and feels like it doesn't respond to the speed I give with my finger. I could do a fast slide up and it would slowly scroll down instead of fast.

Is this a known problem? Could it be something I am doing wrong? How can I fix this? Are there any scroll properties I could change?

listview view :

```
<kendo-mobile-view id="result" ng-controller='resultController' k-reload="true">        
    <kendo-mobile-header>
        <section kendo-mobile-nav-bar class="navbar">
            <kendo-mobile-view-title>{{::resultsLength}} {{::'res_header_result' | translate }}</kendo-mobile-view-title>
            <kendo-mobile-button k-align="'left'" k-icon="'back'" ng-click="back()"></kendo-mobile-button>
            <kendo-mobile-button ng-click="collapse()" k-transition="'slide:left'" k-align="'right'" k-icon="'sort'" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#sortmenu" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample" style="margin-right:1em;"></kendo-mobile-button>
            <kendo-mobile-button k-transition="'slide:left'" k-align="'right'" k-icon="'filter'" href="#view/filter.html"></kendo-mobile-button>
        </section>
    </kendo-mobile-header>
    <div class="collapse" id="sortmenu">
        <div class="list-group">
            <a class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" ng-click="setSort('0');" href="#sortmenu" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample"><span id="filter_item_0" class="filter_arrow"></span>{{::'res_newest_filt' | translate }}</a>
            <a class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" ng-click="setSort('10');" href="#sortmenu" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample"><span id="filter_item_10" class="filter_arrow"></span>{{::'res_rent_filt' | translate }}{{::'res_asc_filt' | translate }}</a>
            <a class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" ng-click="setSort('11');" href="#sortmenu" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample"><span id="filter_item_11" class="filter_arrow"></span>{{::'res_rent_filt' | translate }}{{::'res_desc_filt' | translate }}</a>
            <a class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" ng-click="setSort('20');" href="#sortmenu" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample"><span id="filter_item_20" class="filter_arrow"></span>{{::'res_size_filt' | translate }}{{::'res_asc_filt' | translate }}</a>
            <a class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" ng-click="setSort('21');" href="#sortmenu" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample"><span id="filter_item_21" class="filter_arrow"></span>{{::'res_size_filt' | translate }}{{::'res_desc_filt' | translate }}</a>
            <a class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" ng-click="setSort('40');" href="#sortmenu" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample"><span id="filter_item_40" class="filter_arrow"></span>{{::'res_available_fr_filt' | translate }}{{::'res_asc_filt' | translate }}</a>
            <a class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" ng-click="setSort('41');" href="#sortmenu" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample"><span id="filter_item_41" class="filter_arrow"></span>{{::'res_available_fr_filt' | translate }}{{::'res_desc_filt' | translate }}</a>
            <a class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" ng-click="setSort('50');" href="#sortmenu" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample"><span id="filter_item_50" class="filter_arrow"></span>{{::'res_available_to_filt' | translate }}{{::'res_asc_filt' | translate }}</a>
            <a class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" ng-click="setSort('51');" href="#sortmenu" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample"><span id="filter_item_51" class="filter_arrow"></span>{{::'res_available_to_filt' | translate }}{{::'res_desc_filt' | translate }}</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <ul kendo-mobile-list-view id="resultList" k-pull-to-refresh="true" k-endless-scroll="true" k-on-click="showAdDetail(kendoEvent)">
        <div class="panel panel-default result_listitem" k-template>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <section class="bold font-size-small" style="width: 100%; line-height: 140%;">
                    <span class="bold">&nbsp;&nbsp;#:title#</span>
                </section>
                <section class="result-content">
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <section class="margin-top-small">
                            <span class="bold">{{::'res_rent' | translate }}</span>
                            <span>#:rent_total#&euro;</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <span class="bold">{{::'res_size' | translate }}</span>
                            <span>#:size#m&sup2;</span>
                        </section>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ul>

</kendo-mobile-view>
```

listview controller function

```
function getData(link) {
    $scope.source = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        type: "json",
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: link
            }
        },
        requestEnd: function(e) {
            var results = e.response._embedded.offers;
            getLocalStorage.addObjectToLocalStorage(results, 'results');
            kendo.mobile.application.hideLoading();
        },
        schema: {
            total: function(response) {
                $scope.resultsLength = response._embedded.offers.length;
                return $scope.resultsLength;
            },
            data: "_embedded.offers"    
        },
        serverPaging: true,
        pageSize: 16
    });
    $("#resultList").data('kendoMobileListView').setDataSource($scope.source);

};
```

Comment: No, it's not a known problem. You must be doing some heavy operations in populating the views for your listview. Without seeing the actual code, no one can help you in this matter.

Comment: Give me a moment to post some code please.

Comment: I pasted some code that you can look at. Please, some feedback would be very helpful.

Comment: The problem appears even with Telerik's own examples... Scrolling isn't smooth.

Comment: Ok, then I believe it's due to the fact that the performance of web-apps does not match with native apps. Try running your app on a high-end device and see if you notice any difference.

Comment: Tried on Z1, S4, same issue. I added the useNativeScrolling property and the problem is gone. However there are some limitations with this approach as stated here : http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/mobile/native-scrolling

Comment: Also, check if app hardware acceleration is switched on, may help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem too. To solve it I initialized the kendo application like so:

if (isChrome())
 {
         window.kendoMobileApplication = new        kendo.mobile.Application($(document.body), {
       **useNativeScrolling: true**
});
}

In other words it seems that if you are targeting android browser you need native scrolling.

Comment: Yup. The only problem is that with native scrolling, pull-to-refresh and infinite scrolling cannot be used. We ended up implementing those features on our own. I wonder why Telerik hasn't done that yet.